# Duplicates in a QIF File?

Tags: perl, duplicate-data, quicken, qif

Does anyone have a good way of deleting duplicate transactions (same date, amount, biller, etc) in a QIF file?  I looked at PERL's Finance:QIF, but it appear to have delete a record function.

Alternatively, does someone have a good QIF --> CSV converter?

Although I am looking at a PERL solution, I am open to other ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Finance::QIF](http://search.cpan.org/~simon/Finance-QIF-1.00/QIF.pm) doesn't really need a delete() method (although it would be handy), because **you can access all the transactions as a list** and manipulate it yourself. The [source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/NMCFARL/Finance-QIF-1.03/QIF.pm) is very straightforward, it would be pretty easy to **add a as_csv() method** to Finance::QIF::Transaction (the module used to store one transaction's data), after which you can **apply your own sort-for-uniqueness method** (e.g. plain old "sort -u").

Comment: Newer version: http://search.cpan.org/~mmcgillis/Finance-QIF-3.02/lib/Finance/QIF.pm